# Under nginx and codeigniter how do i redirect certain pages from http to https

Tags: nginx, codeigniter

I want that certain pages to be available on https but not on http. I have a Code Igniter framework there.

Here is the code from nginx conf:

```
server {
   listen         80;
   ......
        #enforce https
        if ($request_uri ~ "^(winkelmandje|(index.php/)?winkelmandje|(index.php/)?history|(index.php/)?mobile/winkelmandje|(index.php/)?winkelmandje/voegtoe)"){
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://$http_host/$1 permanent;
        }
....
}

server {
  listen      443;
  ssl         on;
   ....
        #enforce http
        if ($request_uri ~ "^(!(index.php/)?winkelmandje|!(index.php/)!mobile/winkelmandje|!(index.php/)?history|assets/|!lib_desktop/|!lib_mobile/|!images/|!widget/|!(index.php/)?winkelmandje/voegtoe)"){
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$http_host/$1 permanent;
        }

   .....
}
```

if i go to my domain/winkelmandje (this page is the cart) on http i do not get redirected to https.

Another example is if i access the domain index on https i do not get redirected on http

Comment: You're unlikely to achieve your security goals that way.  Why do you want *any* pages to not use SSL?

Comment: Well i want only the basket, secure checkout and order history to be on https. The rest of the pages must be on http

Comment: I asked *why*.  The reason I ask is that I suspect you're worried about the SSL overhead.  The overhead is tiny and not worth worrying about.  But if you share session cookies between the SSL and non-SSL parts of the site then anyone who can see the non-SSL traffic can just log in as that user using their cookie.  So if you don't have the `secure` attribute in your cookies, you might as well not bother having SSL at all.  If you want security, make the whole site SSL.

Comment: I made it work! I removed the ! in the ssl and removed the ^ from http and https (because request_uri contains the domain as well).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `!` in the https server directive and remove the `^` from http and https (because request_uri contains the domain as well).

```
server {
   listen         80;
   ......
        #enforce https
        if ($request_uri ~ "(winkelmandje|(index.php/)?winkelmandje|(index.php/)?history|(index.php/)?mobile/winkelmandje|(index.php/)?winkelmandje/voegtoe)"){
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://$http_host/$1 permanent;
        }
....
}

server {
  listen      443;
  ssl         on;
   ....
        #enforce http
        if ($request_uri ~ "(!(index.php/)?winkelmandje|!(index.php/)!mobile/winkelmandje|!(index.php/)?history|assets/|!lib_desktop/|!lib_mobile/|!images/|!widget/|!(index.php/)?winkelmandje/voegtoe)"){
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$http_host/$1 permanent;
        }

   .....
}
```